# Camel SFTP username has special character

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have to modify an existing camel SFTP project made in Camel (2.10.2). I am working with Camel for the first time and don't have any knowledge on this.

There are some URI's already configured in `uri="sftp://username@hostname?password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` format which are working fine.
I have to add URI for new host in the same camel. The problem is username for new host name has @ in it (eg: user@name).So new URI configuration does not work in existing format.

I tried to read some manuals and based on those, below are configurations tried so far :

1. `uri="sftp://user@name@hostname?password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` -> It gave 'host must be specified and not empty' error.
2. `uri="sftp://RAW(user@name)@hostname?password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` -> Not able to connect
3. `uri="sftp://hostname?username=RAW(user@name)&amp;password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` -> Not able to connect
4. `uri="sftp://hostname?username=user@name&amp;password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` -> Not able to connect
5. `uri="sftp://hostname?username=user@name?password=XXX&amp;option=value.."` -> Not able to connect
6. `uri="sftp://hostname?username=user@name?password=XXX&amp;option=value..@amp;binary=true"` -> Not able to connect
7. `uri="sftp://hostname?username=RAW(user@name)?password=XXX&amp;option=value..@amp;binary=true"` -> Not able to connect

Its seems RAW(XXX) works in higher version of camel but not in 2.10.2. I have also verified connectivity with hostname and there is no issue with it.

Can somebody help with correct URI format that can work in camel 2.10.2.
Username: user@name, password: XXX, hostname: XXX.YYY.ZZ

Comment: `RAW` is since 2.11.x (which was released 7 years ago btw), it is not available in 2.10.x.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative of RAW that can work in 2.10.x?